# What is Wiener's conditional measure and how can I operate with it?

Tags: measure-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, wiener-measure

For any integer $n$, any choice of $0 < t_1 < \cdots < t_n \leq 1$, and any Lebesgue measurable set, $E \in \mathbb{R}^n$ define the “cylinder”
$$I = I(n;t_1;\cdots;t_n;E) := \{ \beta(·) \in C_0[0,1];(\beta(t_1),\cdots,\beta(t_n)) \in E\}.$$
Let $\mathcal{A}$ be the class of intervals containing all the $I$ for all $n,t_1,\cdots,t_n$ and all Lebesgue measurable sets $E \in \mathbb{R}^n$,
then $\mathcal{A}$ is an algebra of sets in $C_0 [0, 1].$

The $I$’s are the cylinder sets upon which we will define Wiener measure, and then standard measure theoretic ideas to extend to all measurable subsets of the infinite dimensional space, $C_0 [0, 1]$. In fact,we define its measure as
$$ \mu(I) = \dfrac{1}{ \sqrt{(2\pi)^n t_1(t_2 - t_1) \cdots (t_n - t_{n-1})}} \int \cdots \int_E  e^{\frac{-u_1^2}{2t_1} - \frac{(u_2 - u_1)^2}{2(t_2 - t_1)} - \cdots - \frac{(u_n - u_{n-1})^2}{2(t_n - t_{n-1})}}du_1 \cdots du_n. $$

The extension of this measure, creates a probability measure called Wiener measure. I'm trying to understand what the **conditional Wiener measure** is and how it works. I'm trying to get some relationship between the Wiener measure of the following sets

$$ A = \{ x(r) \in E, 0 \leq r \leq t | \, x(0) = x \, , x(t) =y \}$$
$$ B =\{ y(l) \in E, 0 \leq l \leq s | \, y(0) = y \, , y(s) =z \}$$
and
$$ C = \{ x(l) \in E, 0 \leq l \leq t+s | \, x(0) = x \, , x(t+s) =z \}  $$

I hope to get some kind of relationship $ \mu (A) \mu(B) \leq \mu (C)$. How can I perform the Wiener measure of these sets, since the cylinders are set to $t>0?$ Is it possible to do something in this direction using the sets $A$, $B$ and $C$ are cylinder intersections? I appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Context ? I think the probability of each of the sets $A,B,C$ is that of a [Brownian bridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brownian_bridge) (henceforth BB) staying in the set $E\,.$ Since
the BB is Gaussian it should be possible to calculate those probabilities explicitly at least when $E$ is an interval.

Comment: You're right, it's actually a Brownian bridge. But I don't know how to do this explicit calculation, I don't even know if it's possible to use the measure I defined, because a problem occurs if $t=0$, maybe the conditional Wiener measure is different from the one I defined, but I didn't find anything about it . Can you help me with this? Also, why do you think you can do the calculation on an interval? Wouldn't it be in a $n$-rectangle?

Comment: The link I gave shows how the BB is a time changed BM. In Karatzas & Shreve *Brownian Motion and Stochastic Calculus* you will find  a doubly infinite series for the probability that a BM stays in an interval. This should be applicable to BB. I have asked for context because I don't quite see how this arduous calculation would help to understand what conditional Wiener measure is and how it works.